# Can't edit custom cells with UITableView as subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view controller that I have a static view up at the top with a button and a tableview that is under it. I'm attempting to create custom cells in the tableview, but I cannot add labels or anything to the cell. Storyboard only allows me to add the labels to the original view or the tableview (but not the cell). How can I get around this?

Here's a picture for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Out of pure "trying everything" I got it fixed by manually dragging a cell into the view and not using the auto generated prototype cells by xcode. It looks like it was a bug with xcode where it's auto generated prototype cells would not let any interaction happen. To fix it, I dragged a UITableView cell from the object list into the tableview and I was able to edit that just fine. Hope this helps someone else out.